# Reading from the beginning of the file without wasting too much memory.

Tags: c++

Currently I am

```
name_file.close();
name_file.clear();
name_file.open(fname.c_str());
```

After every time my loop resets.

But is that wasting memory.

Comment: Why don't you measure and find out?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]. What is your file containing and what is your program doing? How big do you expect your file to be (a few hundred lines, or a petabyte)? And why do wasting memory is so important to you? Many programs read and parse their input file and put it somehow entirely in memory, so I don't see why do you bother.

Comment: You need to ask an actual specific question. Including a minimal verifiable code example would help too. What exactly is `name_file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are wasting resources. 
Your code works but it could be much better. 
Simply use

```
name_file.seekg(0);
```

This would allow you to read from the beggining of the file. 
Read this for more info about files: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Don't forget `seekp(0)`, if the OP needs to rewrite from the beginning.